# Rails testing button functionality with capybara.

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, capybara, guard

I have this code, I am trying to click on the button to test its functionality using guard and capybara. I get an undefined method error on guard when I have it written like this. It comes back with no errors if I comment out the click_button line. It should render a response that the import was successful as well which is being displayed by an index page.

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'spec_helper'

RSpec.describe "Imports", type: :request do
  it "checks the import page." do
    get '/imports'
    click_button "submit"
  end
end
```

Comment: Is the button labeled "submit" or "Submit"?  Capybara is case sensitive.

Comment: it is submit, thanks.

Comment: This is for sure a button right?  Not a link which is styled like a button?  You could easily confirm in Firebug/equivalent or page source.

Answer (score 0):

how long does the it take to load the element? if > 2 seconds (capybara default wait time is 2s) then it's most likely you will get the undefined method error...

Try increasing capybara's timeout or do it for that element only:

```
click_button "submit", wait: 10
```

If that doesn't solve your issue then assure "submit" is the correct path to your element...

Answer (score 0):

By default Capybara::DSL is only included in tests of type :feature, are you also including it in type :request?